# Magento 2.3 Dynamic comment in system.xml group?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, system.xml, system-config

I need a way of adding a group comment that is dynamic, as I need to pass the stores URL (it gets added as a return URL for a 3rd party service)

It seems like it used to be possible, using a model for the comment, but that is no longer possible due to the `system.xsd` and `system_file.xsd` schemas.

Is there a way to achieve this in Magento 2.3?

Comment: Have you tried using a model for the comment? And it doesn't work?

Comment: As stated, a model is not allowed in a comment that is a child of a group, due to the XSD schema. Currently, my work around it to use a comment on a field element, as that CAN use a model, which is annoying.